# How to get rid of duplicate file names using python

Tags: python

I need help formulating new code in my script that reads through the files scrapped and if there are any duplicates of filename (not the file type) then remove it from the directory. Thanks in advance! Here is my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import os

url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Pages/House-Price-Index-Datasets.aspx#mpo")

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, from_encoding=url.info().get_param('charset'))

FHFA = os.chdir('C:/US_Census/Directory')

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv', '.xml', '.xls', '.xlsx', '.sql', '.txt', '.json']):
        continue

    filename = href.split('/')[-1]
    url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.fhfa.gov/' + href, filename)
    print(filename)

print(' ')
print("All files successfully downloaded.")
```

Comment: Can you include what output you are getting now, and what output you want.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do and the problem you have. An example of input and expected output would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code retrieves filenames such as:

```
HPI_master.csv
HPI_master.xml
HPI_master.sql
...
```

Understandably, you want only the first one, discarding the rest.

You can add a `set` to keep track of seen filenames:

```
seen = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.csv', '.xml', '.xls', '.xlsx', '.sql', '.txt', '.json']):
        continue

    file = href.split('/')[-1]
    filename = file.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    if filename not in seen: # only retrieve file if it has not been seen before
        seen.add(filename)  # add the file to the set
        url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.fhfa.gov/' + href, file)
```

Comment: @bhammer Sorry. Try it now. It should be `seen = set()`

Comment: @bhammer How can `seen` be a tuple? It is a set... :/ Please show me your code.

Comment: Note that `filename` includes the extension, thus it will download both `"HPI_master.csv"` and `"HPI_master.xls"` if both of them exists

Comment: @UriGoren Nice catch. Fixed.

Comment: @bhammer Yes. You aren't allowed to scrape files from that site apparently.  You should open a new question as that has nothing to do with duplicating files. Accept an answer you like, and open a new question.

Comment: @UriGoren Thank you. I usually return the favour but I have exhausted all my votes for today xD

Answer (score 0):

Add a `set` of previous files you've already seen

```
seen = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    href = link.get('href')
    splitted = href.replace('/','.').split('.')
    if len(splitted)<2:
        continue
    filename, fileext = splitted[-2:]
    if href.find('.')<0 or not (fileext.lower() in ['csv', 'xml', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'sql', 'txt', 'json']):
        continue
    if filename in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(filename)
    url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.fhfa.gov/' + href, filename+'.'+fileext)
    print(filename)
```

Comment: I keep receiving the error, "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)". It has to do with the line: "filename, fileext = href.replace('/','.').split('.')[-2:]". Do you know why this is occurring?

Comment: Yes, it is because the script encountered links that do not lead to files, fixed it

Comment: Awesome it is working except it is now getting rid of the ending of the filename so instead of "HPI_master.csv" it is "HPI_master". Any way we can keep the file formats?

Comment: No, I know I used what you edited and everything is being scrapped, but it is taking away the file formats. So if it was a .csv or .txt file, now its just a file. I need it to run so if a ."HPI_master.csv" is the first file it remains "HPI_master.csv" when its pulled into my directory not "HPI_master".

Comment: I am receiving the same error for your code and @ColdSpeed code. It reads: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'HPI_master.csv' ". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: This is an OS related issue, or the server blocked you, please accept and answer or at least up-vote if my answer was helpful

Comment: How can the server block me if I was successfully scraping this website before I tried deleting duplicates?

Comment: If you run too many `HTTP` requests too quickly, they can block your IP to avoid a `DoS` attack, this is unrelated to this question, please ask another one if you'll need help dealing with it.